# How to implement this in awk or shell?

Tags: perl, shell, join, sed, awk

Input File1:

```
5 5 NA
NA NA 1
2 NA 2
```

Input File2:

```
1 1 1
2 NA 2
3 NA NA
NA 4 4
5 5 5
NA NA 6
```

Output:

```
3 NA NA
NA 4 4
NA NA 6
```

The purpose is: in file1 , set any item of each line that is not `NA` into a set, then in file2, eliminate the line that whose fields are within this set. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: why isn't `1 1 1` in the output?

Comment: @dogbane Because `1` appears as `NA NA 1` in file1

Comment: Then why do you say "set first item ... that is not NA"?  `1` does not appear as the first element of any line in `File1`.

Comment: Ah...you mean "in each line of File1, find the first entry that is not `NA` and add it to the set of elements to be deleted".

Comment: Every line in File1 has an NA on it. Do you just want to delete all lines from File2 that contain a number that appears anywhere in File1?

Comment: @EdMorton yes.. that's what I mean..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add *any* item not 'NA':

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i != "NA") {
            a[$i]++
        }
    }
    next
}

{
    for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        if ($j in a) {
            next
        }
    }
}1
```

Results:

```
3 NA NA
NA 4 4
NA NA 6
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i != "NA") a[$i]++; next } { for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if ($j in a) next }1' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `grep`:

```
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+' file1 | fgrep -wvf - file2
3 NA NA
NA 4 4
NA NA 6
```

Answer (score 0):

awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!="NA"){a[$i];break} next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in a)next;}1' file1 file2
```

with your data:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!="NA"){a[$i];break;} next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in a)next;}1' file1 file2
3 NA NA
NA 4 4
NA NA 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column position of the values matters:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i!="NA") A[i,$i]=1
    next
  }
  {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i!=NA && A[i,$i]) next
    print 
  }
' file1 file2
```